# Is it possible for android app to get user's timeline?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-timeline

I am a newbie to Facebook so I really don't have much idea of what is timeline. I simply understand Timeline as a tool which shows user's action history.

You are more than welcome to point out if my understanding is wrong.

Anyways, I am wondering I can show my user's timeline from Android app. I saw some tutorials how to add app to user's timeline but simply don't know how to show user's timeline from android app. Is it possible? If possible, could you give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your starting point: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/screenshots/android/

Comment: thx DMCS.. According to document you referenced, looks like I cant request timeline. well.. then I will not use timeline for my app